# TFLearn stuck while fitting network involving tf.map_fn()

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, tflearn

My code here is

```
     ...
     network = fully_connected(network, 512, activation='relu')
     print(network)
     #network = tf.map_fn(lambda x:tf.abs(x), network)
    network=...
```

(the `tf.abs` op is just as an example, I've tried other functions, including a function that does nothing but returns the input, but none of these helps)

By commenting the third line, the program will stuck at here forever:

```
Preprocessing... Calculating std over all dataset (this may take long)...
STD: 0.30816 (To avoid repetitive computation, add it to argument 'std' of `add_featurewise_stdnorm`)
INFO:tensorflow:Summary name Accuracy/ (raw) is illegal; using Accuracy/__raw_ instead.
---------------------------------
Training samples: 55000
Validation samples: 10000
```

I am not sure what to do by now.